# Is there a way to read integers inside brackets with scanf?

Tags: c, int, scanf

I want to read three integers inside brackets with scanf.

I've tried some codes, like: 1)`%*c`, 2)`scanf("(%d, %d, %d)", &x, &y, &a);` ...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int m, n, s, x, y, a;

  scanf("%d %d",&m, &n );
  scanf("%d", &s );
  scanf("(%d, %d, %d)", &x, &y, &a);
  printf("x é: %d\n y é: %d\n a é: %d\n", x, y, a);
  return 0;
}
```

I expected the output of:

```
12 23
2
(12, 34, 52)
```

to be:

```
x is: 12
y is: 34
a is: 52
```

but the actual output is:

```
x is: 1942163568
y is: 21945
a is: 1800188064
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question... `./prog <<< '(1, 2, 3)'` works fine using `scanf("(%d, %d, %d)", &x, &y, &z)`, nothing fancy really.

Comment: Do not use `x,y,a` until after checking return value of `scanf()` --> e.g. `if (scanf("%*[(]%d, %d, %d%*[)]", &x, &y, &a) != 3) puts("Something wrong, review expected input and code");`

Comment: Suspect posted code is from larger code and `'\n'` not read.  Put `" "` before `"%*[(]"`.   Please post exact input used.

Comment: @chux , you're right. Now I posted the exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need space before `"("` - something to consume the `'\n'` from the end of `"2\n"`.

Suggest liberal use of `" "` in the format before `'('`, `')'`, `','` to consume optional white-space.  `"%d"` already consume leading white-space.

```
// scanf("(%d, %d, %d)", &x, &y, &a);
if (scanf(" (%d ,%d ,%d )", &x, &y, &a) != 3) puts("Oops");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it.

First as mentioned in comment.

Method 1.

```
scanf("(%d, %d, %d)", &x, &y, &a);
```

Method 2.

```
char str[100] = {'\0'};
fgets(str, 99, stdin);

sscanf(str, "(%d, %d, %d)", &x, &y, &a);
```

Comment: Like chux said, I didn't post the entire code. With the short code, the first mentioned comment works fine.